# i have created link between list of students name and there profile

Tags: php

The link is working  well when i click on any name of student it's going to profile page but in profile page its not fetching data from database through id and the link is not passing id can anyone solve it. Thanks in advance.

This is name list page

```
<?php

    $query="SELECT id,name,fname,phone FROM  student"; 
$resultset=$connection->query($query); 

$count=0; 
while($r=$resultset->fetch_assoc()){
    $count++; 
echo "<tr><td>".$count."</td><td><a href='student_profile.php?id='".$r["id"]."'>".$r["name"]."</a></td><td>".$r["fname"]."</td><td></td><td><td>".$r["phone"]."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='chb".$count."' value='".$r["id"]."'></td></tr>
"; 

}
?>
```

This is profile page

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$result=$connection->query("SELECT name,fname,gender,email,phone,address,image FROM student WHERE id=".$id."");

$rs=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: are you getting id on the profile page ... print $id

Comment: In the url does it say student_profile.php?id=29 for example?

Comment: no it say student_profile.php?id=

Comment: i am getting profile page but its empty

Comment: So something is wrong with your first page. Is it connecting? in the while loop do echo $['id']; and see if anything comes through

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put a **'** after **id='** which means your href link ended after id= 
Try removing the **'**

From this

```
_profile.php?id='".$r["id"]."'>
```

To this

_profile.php?id=".$r["id"]."'>

Comment: thanks its working but when i use Post instead of get its not working

Comment: $id = intval($_GET['id']);

Comment: You create a form with hidden inputs that hold the values to be posted, set the action of the form to the destination url, and the form method to post.

Comment: name list page is also in form and method is post but the action is delete page .

Comment: You can perform both on same page using if(isset())

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Give different button names like delete or list, and in post action page check if(isset($_POST['delete'])){ //do deletion } else if(isset(......